# Date format in words for today and yesterday in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am creating a new conversations app where the conversation messages gets displayed on the date ascending, I have done this:

```
messages = conversation.messages.group_by { |message|
  message.created_at.strftime('%m%d%Y')
}
```

and I am displaying messages with this key (grouped date). How can I display today's and yesterday's messages as today and yesterday?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about `Today`, `Tomorrow` but you can use `distance_of_time_in_words` method to show when message is created.

```
2.3.1 :031 > require 'action_view'
 => false 
2.3.1 :032 > include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
 => Object 
2.3.1 :033 > distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Time.now) + ' ago'
 => "less than a minute ago" 
2.3.1 :034 > distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Time.now - 1.hour) + ' ago'
 => "about 1 hour ago" 
2.3.1 :035 > distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Time.now - 90.minutes) + ' ago'
 => "about 2 hours ago" 
2.3.1 :036 > distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Time.now - 1.day) + ' ago'
 => "1 day ago" 
2.3.1 :037 > distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, Time.now - 5.day) + ' ago'
 => "5 days ago"
```

You can also use gems like [`dotiw`](https://github.com/elgalu/time_ago_in_words)